# My apex class code coverage is showing zero percentage on writing the test class

Tags: apex, unit-test, code-coverage, failing-tests

Apex class:

```
public class GenRangoTarjeta_cls {// OJCB v 1.4 This class generates a range of cards concatenating the program code and country code 
      public static void addRangoTarjeta (Card_Rate__c rangs, String prefpro, String prepai, String country) { 
          rangs.Rango_inicial_Num__c = Long. valueOf (rangs.Rango_Inicial__c); 
          System.debug ('RankInicialnum:' + rangs.Rango_Inicial_Num__c); 
          rangs.Rango_Final_Num__c = Long.valueOf (rangs.Rango_Final__c); 
          System.debug ('FinalFinal Range:' + rangs.Rango_Final_Num__c); 
          rangs.Rango_Inicial__c = prefpro + prepai + rangs.Rango_Inicial__c; 
          System.debug ('Initial Rangeconcat:' + rangs.Rango_inicial__c); 
          rangs.Rango_Final__c = prefpro + prepai + rangs.Rango_Final__c;
          System.debug ('FinalConcat Range:' + rangs.Rango_Final__c);    
          rangs.Reference__c = prepai + prefpro + country; 
      } 
    }
```

Test Class:

```
@isTest
private class Test_GenRangoTarjeta_cls {//OJCB v 1.4 clase de pruebas para generar rangos
    public static testMethod void t1(){
        Tipo_Programa__c myTipoProg = new Tipo_Programa__c(Name='Programa de prueba', Pais__c='Guatemala', Programa__c='VB',Codigo_Pais__c='01');
        try {
            insert myTipoProg;
            system.debug ('\n\nEl tipo de programa:'+myTipoProg);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('\n\nError t1 creando tipo programa: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='000011', Rango_Final__c='000015', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango;
            system.debug (myRango);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort1: '+e);
        }  
   } 
   public static testMethod void t2(){
        Tipo_Programa__c myTipoProg = new Tipo_Programa__c(Name='Programa de prueba', Pais__c='Guatemala', Programa__c='VB',Codigo_Pais__c='01');
        try {
            insert myTipoProg;
            system.debug ('\n\nEl tipo de programa:'+myTipoProg);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('\n\nError t1 creando tipo programa: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='00000025', Rango_Final__c='00000040', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango;
            system.debug (myRango);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort2: '+e);
        } 
   } 
   public static testMethod void t3(){
        Tipo_Programa__c myTipoProg = new Tipo_Programa__c(Name='Programa de prueba', Pais__c='Guatemala', Programa__c='VB',Codigo_Pais__c='01');
        try {
            insert myTipoProg;
            system.debug ('\n\nEl tipo de programa:'+myTipoProg);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('\n\nError t1 creando tipo programa: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='0000090', Rango_Final__c='0000080', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango;
            system.debug (myRango);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort3: '+e);
        }       
    }
    public static testMethod void t4(){
        Tipo_Programa__c myTipoProg = new Tipo_Programa__c(Name='Programa de prueba', Pais__c='Guatemala', Programa__c='VB',Codigo_Pais__c='01');
        try {
            insert myTipoProg;
            system.debug ('\n\nEl tipo de programa:'+myTipoProg);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('\n\nError t1 creando tipo programa: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='000011', Rango_Final__c='000015', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango;
            system.debug (myRango);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort4: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango2 = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='000012', Rango_Final__c='000014', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango2;
            system.debug (myRango2);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort4: '+e);
        }   
   }
   public static testMethod void t5(){
        Tipo_Programa__c myTipoProg = new Tipo_Programa__c(Name='Programa de prueba', Pais__c='Guatemala', Programa__c='VB',Codigo_Pais__c='01');
        try {
            insert myTipoProg;
            system.debug ('\n\nEl tipo de programa:'+myTipoProg);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('\n\nError t1 creando tipo programa: '+e);
        }
        Rango_Tarjetas__c myRango = new Rango_Tarjetas__c(Rango_Inicial__c='000018', Rango_Final__c='000001', Tipo_Programa__c=myTipoProg.Id);
        try {
            insert myRango;
            system.debug (myRango);
        } catch (System.DmlException e) {
            system.debug ('Errort5: '+e);
        }          
   }

    }
```

Could you please help me in finding the issue.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your test class doesn't call your code. How are you expecting it to be covered? Is there other code, such as a trigger, involved?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I observe that there is no explicit call to the `addRangoTarjeta()` which is the actual method that needs to be verified. How is the `addRangoTarjeta()` invoked anyway?

Ideally your test methods in the test class should be written as follows. Add the other methods accordingly I am only including `t1()` as an example.

```
@isTest
private class Test_GenRangoTarjeta_cls {

    public static testMethod void t1(){

        Card_Rate__c rangsInstance = new Card_Rate__c();

        test.startTest();

        //Invoke the rangs.Reference__c method to verify the behaviour
        GenRangoTarjeta_cls.addRangoTarjeta(
            rangsInstance,
            'prefpro string',       
            'prepai string',
            'country string'
        );

        test.stopTest();

        //Checking if the reference value is concatenated as expected
        System.assertEquals(
            'prefpro string' + 'prepai string' + 'country string', 
            rangsInstance.Reference__c);
        );
    }
}
```